# Recursive loop in BigQuery for capped cumulative sum?

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I'd like to be able to implement a "capped" cumulative sum in BigQuery using SQL.

Here's what I mean: I have a table whose rows have the amount by which a value is increased/decreased each day, but the value cannot go below 0 or above 100. I want to compute the cumulative sum of the changes to keep track of this value.

As an example, consider the following table:

```
day | change 
--------------
1   | 70
2   | 50
3   | 20
4   | -30
5   | 10
6   | -90
7   | 20
```

I want to make a column that has the capped cumulative sum so that it looks like this:

```
day | change | capped cumsum
----------------------------
1   | 70     | 70
2   | 50     | 100
3   | 20     | 100
4   | -30    | 70
5   | 10     | 80
6   | -90    | 0
7   | 20     | 20
```

Simply doing `SUM (change) OVER (ORDER BY day)` and capping the values at 100 and 0 won't work. I need some sort of recursive loop and I don't know how to implement this in BigQuery.

---

Eventually I'd also like to do this over partitions, so that if I have something like

```
day | class | change 
--------------
1   | A     | 70
1   | B     | 12
2   | A     | 50
2   | B     | 83
3   | A     | -30
3   | B     | 17
4   | A     | 10
5   | A     | -90
6   | A     | 20
```

I can do the capped cumulative sum partitioned over each class.

Answer (score 1):

> I need some sort of recursive loop and I don't know how to implement this in BigQuery

Super naïve / cursor based approach

```
declare cumulative_change int64 default 0;

create temp table temp_table as (
  select * , 0 as capped_cumsum from your_table where false
);

for rec in (select * from your_table order by day)
do
  set cumulative_change = cumulative_change + rec.change;
  set cumulative_change = case when cumulative_change < 0 then 0 when cumulative_change > 100 then 100 else cumulative_change end;
  insert into temp_table (select rec.*, cumulative_change);
end for;

select * from temp_table order by day;
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Slightly modified option with use of array instead of temp table

```
declare cumulative_change int64 default 0;
declare result array<struct<day int64, change int64, capped_cumsum int64>>;
 
for rec in (select * from your_table order by day)
do
  set cumulative_change = cumulative_change + rec.change;
  set cumulative_change = case when cumulative_change < 0 then 0 when cumulative_change > 100 then 100 else cumulative_change end;
  set result = array(select as struct * from unnest(result) union all select as struct rec.*, cumulative_change);
end for;

select * from unnest(result) order by day;
```

P.S. I like none of above options so far :o)
Meantime, that approach might work for relatively small tables, set of data

Comment: Thanks, this is something that I can start playing with. How might I modify this to get the capped_cumsum over each partition?

Comment: yes. i think this can be good start for you. try to make it work first assuming just one partition. as of multi-partition case - should be doable to enhance above for it - but first try by yourself and if still problem  - post new question with all details and the progress you hopefully will have  - and we will be happy to further help :o)

Answer (score 1):

> Eventually I'd also like to do this over partitions ...

Consider below solution

```
create temp function cap_value(value int64, lower_boundary int64, upper_boundary int64) as (
  least(greatest(value, lower_boundary), upper_boundary)
 ); 
with recursive temp_table as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by class order by day) as n from your_table
), iterations as (
  select 1 as n, day, class, change, cap_value(change, 0, 100) as capped_cumsum 
  from temp_table 
  where n = 1
    union all
  select t.n, t.day, t.class, t.change, cap_value(i.capped_cumsum + t.change, 0, 100) as capped_cumsum 
  from temp_table t
  join iterations i
  on t.n = i.n + 1 
  and t.class = i.class
)
select * except(n) from iterations
order by class, day
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `RECURSIVE CTE` can be another option:

```sql
DECLARE sample ARRAY<STRUCT<day INT64, change INT64>> DEFAULT [
 (1, 70), (2, 50), (3, 20), (4, -30), (5, 10), (6, -90), (7, 20)
];

WITH RECURSIVE ccsum AS (
  SELECT 0 AS n, vals[OFFSET(0)] AS change, 
         CASE 
           WHEN vals[OFFSET(0)] > 100 THEN 100
           WHEN vals[OFFSET(0)] < 0 THEN 0 
           ELSE vals[OFFSET(0)] 
         END AS cap_csum 
    FROM sample
   UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS n, vals[OFFSET(n + 1)] AS change,
         CASE 
           WHEN cap_csum + vals[OFFSET(n + 1)] > 100 THEN 100
           WHEN cap_csum + vals[OFFSET(n + 1)] < 0 THEN 0 
           ELSE cap_csum + vals[OFFSET(n + 1)] 
         END AS cap_csum
    FROM ccsum, sample 
   WHERE n < ARRAY_LENGTH(vals) - 1
),
sample AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(change ORDER BY day) vals FROM UNNEST(sample)
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(n) FROM ccsum ORDER BY n;
```

output:

[image]